# Code highlighting in CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

How can I highlight the code section and reserved words for common languages like c/c++/Php etc ? I have tried the GeSHi Filter, but it does not work with the CKEditor. Am I doing something wrong ? Can anyone suggest some workable solution for the CKEditor?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why the [GeShi filter](http://drupal.org/project/geshifilter) didn't work for you?

Comment: @DavidThomas I have followed the instructions as in GeSHi Filter and assume when I use <code> ..</code> tag it should highlight. But  I dont see it happening. I have tried with different input filters ( full html, php code etc) also with no luck. I don't have any clue as to why it does not.

Comment: Worth noting that I had a similar problem where it wasn't being processed. It finally started processing when I used the [] tags instead of <>. Haven't a clue why, but that fixed it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with the Geshi Filter, you could try the alternative http://drupal.org/project/syntaxhighlighter module.